# Find data variables from raw data in paraview

Tags: data-science, data-visualization, visualization, paraview, raw-data

I have been given a raw volume data file and I am trying to figure out the data fields and variables in that data using Paraview. Tried different tutorials from the ParaView wiki and other videos from youtube. But none of them has any specific solution. I was able to apply different display representations such as slicing and volume in ParaView and find a pattern inside the volume data. But now, I need to find the data variables. Is there any way to find out the data variables and fields from the raw data file?

Answer (score 1):

Different answer, depending on what you are looking for exactly:

- the [Information Panel](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/understandingData.html#the-information-panel) gives a list of data, with type and range
- the [SpreadSheet view](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/displayingData.html?highlight=spreadsheet#spreadsheet-view) gives, hem, a spreadsheet. So one line per point or cell with associated data
- the [FindData panel](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/selectingData.html?highlight=find%20data#creating-selections-using-the-find-data-panel), to explore and pick point or cell depending on data value.

Comment: I tried to see using those options but couldn’t. Paraview doesn’t show options. It just simply show buttons disabled. Is there any other way to find the data inside .raw file. I mean without using paraview. If that’s possible I could convert the file ... right?

Comment: Can you details the step you did ?

Comment: I loaded data and after numerous trial and error, I was able to get a fishbone 3d image inside that. But I wasn't able to get the data. So I selected "Selection Display Inspector" from the View menu. Then I select "Interactive select points on". But I can't see and value while hovering on the image. At the same time, I believe I can select a certain area to view the data. but I am not able to do the same.